# Exporting a c++ dll class unexpected behavoir

Tags: c++, windows

I am farily new to c++ language and have an extensive c# background.
I have setup a solution in visual studio 2022 consisting of a console executable project and a dll project, with the excutable depending on the dll project.

The dll depends on some other static libs to ultimatly provide httpclient like functionality.

These projects are a play ground for me to understand more about c++.
I decided I want a c# like functionalty between the exe and dll, so I exported a class from the dll `class MyHttpClient`.

My first atempt was to export this class as a whole, but that resulted in the exe having dependancy on some of the libs the dll depends on due to the class having member fields whose types come from these libs, even though the build was successfull the exe would crash..

So I decided to make an interface class with only a public constructor and key public functions in a seperate clean headerfile; this class has the same name and inside the same name space as the full class, I decorated this abstract class with `__declspec(dllexport)` using a predefined macro to `__decspec(dllexport/import)` the class based on the project it is in, and imported this headerfile into my exe main file.
p.s. please note that the full class is also decorated with `__declspec(dllexport)`.

```
//inteface.h
#include "def.h"
//This is the abstract(interface) class
class EXPORT_API MyHttpClient
{
   public:
      MyHttpClient();
      std::string Get();
};
```

main.cpp in exe includes the interface.h file.

```
//MyHttpClient.h
//Multiple #include "def.h" ...
class EXPORT_API MyHttpClient
{
   public:
      MyHttpClient();
      std::string Get();
   private:
    // some member fields
};
```

```
//MyHttpClient.cpp
provides implementation for the MyHttpClient class
```

Now here is what happens:

```
#include "inteface.h"
int main()
{
// if I declare the class's object on the stack everything works as intended.
  MyHttpClient client;
  auto result = client.Get();

//if I set it on the heap the program crashes with Access violation
// on the private members as if they were not there!!
  HttpClient* cli = new HttpClient;
  auto result = cli->Get(); // crash
...
}
```

Q1: Why do I see such behavior?
I suspect that the new operator calls size of the abstract class and
thus all the fields have no memory allocated, while the stack calls the
construtor (where these members are initialized) and expands as these
members are initialzed (that is my speculation but I really dont know!).

Q2:How to remdy this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Two distinct headers for the same class is asking for trouble. There are better techniques to hide  implementation details of a library e.g. the [PImpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl).

Comment: @Scheff's Cat that was just to simplify the question, I am well aware of header guards.

Comment: Just because you only export X from a DLL doesn't mean that dependencies in the DLL to other libraries magically disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I decided to make an interface class with only a public constructor and key public functions in a seperate clean headerfile; this class has the same name and inside the same name space as the full class

That violates the one-definition-rule and causes your program to have undefined behavior. Definitions of the same class in different translation units must be formed by identical token sequences (plus some additional requirements).

If you want an abstract class as interface, use inheritance and (pure) virtual functions.

Comment: correct me if  I am wrong : classes are the exception to the One-Definition-Rule given that the duplicate difinitions appear in seperate translation units. based on this assumption I wanted to abuse the linker with multiple declaration of the same class in 2 seperate header files and one cpp file providing the implemntation, which I was successfull in doing so, but only if I let the object reside on the stack, plus why I dont get a linker compiler error if it is really multiple definition for the same class ?!!

Comment: @Ra'edJaradat No, they are an exception in the sense that they can have more than one definition at all, but if they have more than one definition, these must be identical, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule: "_There can be more than one definition in a program of each of the following: class type [...] as long as all of the following is true: [...] each definition consists of the same sequence of tokens_".

Comment: @Ra'edJaradat Violating the one-definition-rule causes undefined behavior. The compiler/linker does not need to (and in general can't) diagnose it. It seemingly working in some cases, but not others is a possible outcome of undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you the clarification , the solution to my problem is to export simply a factory function that returns a pointer to the interface type, while the full class now inheherits the interface type and gets instantiated in the  
 factory function and get returned as the base (interface class).